# Converting from Hexadecimal to 2's complement

Tags: c

Im trying to convert a given hexadecimal to a 2's complement number, but something odd occurs in my program. (The assignment is to take two given numbers that can be either octal, binary, hex, or decimal, add/subtract them, then convert to the given base)

I use the command:  ./a.out + x1111 x1111 x

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char* arg[]){
  int num1=0, num2=0, converted = 0;
  if ((argc < 5) || (argc > 5))
  {
    printf("ERROR: please enter input in the following format\n");
    printf("/calc <operation> <number1> <number2> <output base>\n");
  }
  else{
    if (arg[2][0] == 'x'){
      num1 = HexAsciiTo2comp(arg[2]);
      printf("%d\n", num1);
    }
    if (arg[3][0] == 'x'){
      num2 = HexAsciiTo2comp(arg[3]);
      printf("%d\n", num2);
    }
  }
  converted = num1 + num2;
  finalOutput(converted, arg[4]);
  return 0;
}

int HexAsciiTo2comp(char* hexNum){
  int value = 0, i = 1;
  printf("The original Hex Value is %s\n", hexNum);
  for(i=1; i<9; i++){
    switch(hexNum[i]){
          case '0': value = value << 4; break;
          case '1': value = (value << 4)+1; break;
          case '2': value = (value << 4)+2; break;
          case '3': value = (value << 4)+3; break;
          case '4': value = (value << 4)+4; break;
          case '5': value = (value << 4)+5; break;
          case '6': value = (value << 4)+6; break;
          case '7': value = (value << 4)+7; break;
          case '8': value = (value << 4)+8; break;
          case '9': value = (value << 4)+9; break;
          case 'A': value = (value << 4)+10; break;
          case 'B': value = (value << 4)+11; break;
          case 'C': value = (value << 4)+12; break;
          case 'D': value = (value << 4)+13; break;
          case 'E': value = (value << 4)+14; break;
          case 'F': value = (value << 4)+15; break;
          default:break;
          }
        }return value;
}
```

and the result ends up being:

```
The original Hex Value is x1111
1118481
The original Hex Value is x1111
4369
```

The latter result of 4369 is correct however the first output isn't. 
Why might this be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for` loop runs as long as `i < 9` is true, but your input string is smaller. This means that you have to also check for the string ending (`i < 9 && hexNum[i] != '\0'`), otherwise you will access data outside of the string.